# property 'code' not found on object of type 'NSError *' on custom NSError

Tags: objective-c, ios

I need another pair of eyes please.

Strangely enough, I can't seem to be able to access properties on my custom NSError. I keep getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS errors. Here's my code:

```
        if (response.isUnauthorized)
        {
            NSDictionary *userInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:response.bodyAsString forKey:@"Error Message"];

            NSError *unAuthorizedError = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"MyApp" code: [response statusCode]  userInfo:userInfo];
            [delegate dataControllerLoadFailed:unAuthorizedError];
            [ErrorHandler logError:unAuthorizedError fromClassName:NSStringFromClass([self class]) fromSelectorName:NSStringFromSelector(_cmd) ]; 
        }
```

and this calls:

```
-(void)dataControllerLoadFailed:(NSError *)error
{
    NSString *message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Encountered an error: %@ - ", error.code];

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"MyApp"
                                                    message:message
                                                   delegate:nil
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    [activityIndicator stopAnimating];

}
```

I get the Bad Access error on creating the message NSString in dataControllerLoadFailed, be it using error.code or any other member on the error object...

so this fails:

```
NSString *message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Encountered an error: %@ - ", error.code];
```

But weirdly enough this succeeds:

```
NSString *message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Encountered an error: %@ - ", error];
```

Thanks to anyone giving this some time!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`code` is an `NSInteger` which is just a typedef'd `int`.  You need to use `%d` not `%@`

Comment: Typically it is better (and the compiler definitely agrees) to use `%ld` and cast the arg to long.

Comment: @Dan F... thanks, geeeesh ok that was an easy one. Why can't error messages in Obj C be more explicit? Just wasted an insane amount of time on a type mismatch error disguised as a BAD_Access error. arrrgn.. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

`EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error generally means that your code expects to have valid objective-c object and you don't have it.

In your case you're using wrong format specifier in NSLog: code property in NSError is plain NSInteger thus you need to use %d specifier, not %@

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Encountered an error: %d - ", error.code];
```

Also keep in mind that if you want to show error info to user it then error code may not be meaningful, you can get human-readable error info using `localizedDescription`, `localizedFailureReason` methods

Comment: I simply used error.code as an example of a NSError member I had trouble accessing.... I definitely won't be showing only the error code to my users ;)